# C simple static variable behaviour mystery

Tags: c, variables, static, behavior

I am learning C right now and have a problem understanding something about the behaviour of a program with a static variable. As far as i know, static simply increases the scope of a variable to the file containing it.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   int sum (int num) {
       static int sum =0;
       sum=sum+num;
       return sum;
   }

   int main() {
       printf("%d ",sum(55));
       printf("%d ",sum(45));
       printf("%d ",sum(50));
       return 0;
   }
```

if i execute this i get `55 100 150` as an output. And that's totally fine and expected.
Then i thought could decraese one line by changing it a little bit like this:

```
int sum (int num) {
       static int sum =0+num;
       return sum;
   }
```

but this returns `55 55 55`
I don't understand why it only returns 55 and doesn't add the other variables, that i am giving in the main to it.

Comment: Static variables are only initialized the first time the function is called.

Comment: `static` (inside a function) changes the lifetime, not the scope

Comment: It's the same reason the first version doesn't keep resetting it to `0` before adding.

Comment: The second program is not allowed in Standard C by the way (initializers of static variables must be constant expressions)

Comment: so the second time the function is called the line `static int sum =0;` will not be executed? or is it rather ignored?

Comment: This is an important instance where a declaration with initializer is not the same as a declaration followed by assignment, although beginners may get in the habit of thinking of them as interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a static variable inside a function instead of outside a function it can only be accessed inside the function. Otherwise it works like a global variable in the sense that it exists throughout the lifetime of the program. Its initial value is determined when the program is compiled so it must be initialized with a constant expression. Any decent compiler should warn you if the initializer is not constant as in your example:

```
$ gcc -o test -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘sum’:
test.c:3:24: error: initializer element is not constant
        static int sum =0+num;
                        ^
```

Note that you should always compile your C programs with warnings enabled.

Comment: Re “When you declare a static variable inside a function instead of outside a function it can only be accessed inside the function”: An **identifier** declared inside a function is visible only inside that function. An **object** defined inside a function without `static` only exists (has memory reserved for it) during that function’s execution, including the time when a function is temporarily suspended (as because it calls a subroutine). The object can in fact be accessed outside the function, by means of pointers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, you can do all sorts of tricks in C.

Comment: This is not about tricks. It is about giving students an accurate model. Stating that an object declared inside a function can only be accessed inside the function is false. And anything false a student learns has to be unlearned later, which is harder.

Answer (score 1):

By default C variables exist only within the block where they are declared. They are said to be of automatic storage class.

By using the keyword `static` you are able to declare a variable of static storage class, i.e. a variable that exist for all the duration of the program.

Even though static variables exist during the whole program execution, they can be accessed only within the block in which they are declared.

Scope and storage class are two different things.

Comment: Re “By default C variables exist only within the block where they are declared”: **Where** is the wrong word to use for existence. Existence is a matter of **when** an object exists (when memory is reserved for it). Objects defined inside functions without `static` exist **while** the function is executing, including while it is executing but suspended (as when it calls a subroutine), until its execution terminates. This means that “they can be accessed only within the block in which they are declared” is incorrect: Objects can be accessed outside of their associated blocks by way of pointers.

Comment: @Postpischil Yes storage class is a matter of time, but when I say "variables exist only within the block **where** they are declared” am I saying that they already exist before to enter the block? Or am I saying that they still exists after exiting the block? As you can see this **where** is pretty much a space-time thing.

Comment: As noted, the mistaken terminology in the first sentence leads to the error in the later sentence: “they can be accessed only within the block in which they are declared” is false. In `void bar(int *p) { printf("%d\n", *p); } void foo(void) { int x; bar(&x); }`, the object named `x` is accessed outside of the block in which it is declared. You may know what you meant, and you may be able to figure out some such interpretation of the words, but such reasoning is of no use to students, who must read the words as they are, not as they exist in the minds of somebody else.

Comment: These concepts are fairly simple and clear and are well defined in the C standard. There is no reason not to use the correct words.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to use wrong words, so I apologize if I did it. Anyway in your example, since you called bar() inside foo(), you didn't exit the block in which `x` has been declared.